# Get all the output from Watson conversation using java

Tags: java, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

If I have a IBM bluemix Watson conversation dialog output JSON like:

```
"output": {
    "text": {
        "values": [
            "What is your name?",
            "Name of the person?",
            "Please specify the name of the person."
        ],
        "selection_policy": "random",
        "append": true
    }
}
```

How can I get all the suggestions from the output response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use context variables for saves what the user says using `<? input.text ?>`. Try to follow this simple example:

Create one child node in this Node above, and add:

```
{
  "context": {
    "userTypes": "<? input.text ?>"
  },
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "All you said here: $userTypes."
      ],
      "selection_policy": "sequential"
    }
  }
}
```

So, in your Java example, you can get the value of this context variable with this follow method:

```
private Map<String, Object> context = new HashMap<>();

 ConversationService service = new ConversationService(ConversationService.VERSION_DATE_2016_09_20);
 service.setUsernameAndPassword('Your Watson service UserName', 'Your watson service PassWord');
 MessageRequest newMessage = new MessageRequest.Builder().inputText(inputmessage).context(context).build();
 MessageResponse response = service.message('Your Workspace Id', newMessage).execute();

   //Passing Context of last conversation
    if(response.getContext() !=null)
      {
        context.clear();

        context = response.getContext();

     }
```

- See more about [Accessing and Evaluate objects](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/expression-language.html#accessing-and-evaluating-objects).
- See more about [methods](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-methods.html) inside Watson Conversation.
- See the official [API Reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/?java#) using Java.
- See one [full example](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/blob/develop/examples/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/developer_cloud/conversation/v1/ConversationExample.java) from IBM Developer's in Watson Developer Cloud.